# Unique topics using MQTT in Android

Tags: android, mqtt

I am trying MQTT with Mosquitto Broker and Android. It's a very cool protocol very fast. I am still documenting now on how to create unique topics. I can have several topics and client to listen to them, but i need to know what to do to have unique topics and clients for each of them. Can i create topics dynamic? For now i am listening to topics written "hard coded".
If you have a link or idea would suffice. I am still googling..
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

All topics in MQTT are designed to be dynamic - although not all brokers support the dynamic creation of topics.

These resources might be useful:

http://mqtt.org/wiki/doku.php/mqtt_on_the_android_platform

http://mqtt.org/wiki/doku.php/are_topics_dynamic

Comment: Hello, i have read the documentation, i understand that a client can create a topic, even if that doesn't exist. But i did not understand how to make sense with what clients and on what action to send a specific message. i hope that makes sense... I am trying to have n clients registered to a broker. Each with a topic. Without using a database(which breaks the "fast" from the hole thing) i don't understand how to remember the clients that registered, or retrieve them from the broker.

Comment: @GabrielaRadu did you find out how to do that?